# timezone aware datetime objects in django templates

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm having trouble understanding how to use datetime objects in a django db.

I'm storing `datetime.now()` in a `DateTimeField` but having trouble displaying it in a readable way. Currently it displays UTC time.

Should I storing a timezone with the datetimefield or should I always be converting it to my timezone during queries and template views?

This is so complicated I must be doing this completely wrong.

How would I display Pacific timezone time in a template if that were the case?

Thank you.

```
<tbody>
  {% for session in session_list %}
      <tr></tr><td>{{session.date}}</td><td>{{session.email}}</td><td>{{session.userData}}</td></tr>
  {% endfor %}

</tbody>
```

Comment: Storing date+time fields in a database in UTC is recommended practice, because UTC is unambiguous. You probably want to find a way to display the time in the *user's* timezone rather than your own.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*) You can enable or disable conversion of aware datetime objects using templates tags:

```
{% load tz %}

{% localtime on %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}

{% localtime off %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}
```

*) In `setting.py`, you can configure `TIME_ZONE` and `USE_TZ`

Store datetime in UTC time is good(below quote from Django website):

> it’s still good practice to store data in UTC in your database. The main reason is Daylight Saving Time (DST). Many countries have a system of DST, where clocks are moved forward in spring and backward in autumn. If you’re working in local time, you’re likely to encounter errors twice a year, when the transitions happen. (The pytz documentation discusses these issues in greater detail.) This probably doesn’t matter for your blog, but it’s a problem if you over-bill or under-bill your customers by one hour, twice a year, every year. The solution to this problem is to use UTC in the code and use local time only when interacting with end users.

Read more from the [official Django Site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/)

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: error: `backports.zoneinfo._common.ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key USE_TZ'`

Answer (score 3):

Just adding an answer as a reference using Django 3.x new syntax:

In template, include tz:

```py
{% load tz %}
```

When displaying your timezone aware object, either use `timezone:'TIMEZONE'` filter or `localtime` filter:

Your code should look like this

```py
<tbody>
  {% for session in session_list %}
      <tr></tr><td>{{session.date|localtime}}</td><td>{{session.email}}</td><td>{{session.userData}}</td></tr>
  {% endfor %}

</tbody>
```

Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/) on Django official website.